# What is the mechanics behind this below update contract balance

Tags: function, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

In below function, how the contract balance is updated by just assigning the msg.value into deposit parameterized variable?

```
function transferToContract(uint256 deposit) public payable { 
   require(msg.value == deposit);
   deposit = msg.value; //how it works?
}
```

I'm trying to find answer about behind the mechanics of the above code.And I'm expecting the precise and to the point answer of this.

Answer (score 0):

SInce your function is marked as `payable` you can send money when you call this function. If you develop an app on Remix, after you deploy the contract, you would have an inbox next to the function to enter the amount. Or if you are interacting with the contract on front-end, you might have a function like this

```
await contract.methods.contribute().send({
    from: accounts[0],
    value:1000000,
  });
```

the `value` that you are sending to the contract will be available to the contract as `msg.value`.